# PHP - Get timestamp for uploaded file transfer completion

Tags: php, date, time, file, ftp

Is it possible to get the date that a file was **uploaded** to FTP? **Not created**.

Its use will be in a system where I upload files for a client to view which will appear on a dynamic page and need to be timestamped with when they were last changed.

I basically need to get the time that the file had finished transferring onto FTP - via an FTP client, uploaded by me.

Comment: interesting, in my case,everytime a file is uploaded, i keep the record in a database with the original name and who uploaded and such

Comment: Ah, I mean upload via FTP though. So I drag the files up onto the server with an FTP client and I want to display the time that the upload was completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use PHP's stat() function. It returns every data that you'll need to know.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php

```
<?php
/* Get file stat */
$stat = stat('C:\php\php.exe');

/*
 * Print file access time, this is the same 
 * as calling fileatime()
 */
echo 'Access time: ' . $stat['atime'];

/*
 * Print file modification time, this is the 
 * same as calling filemtime()
 */
echo 'Modification time: ' . $stat['mtime'];

/* Print the device number */
echo 'Device number: ' . $stat['dev'];
?>
```

I think that in your case "file modification time" is the answer.

Comment: Every file that is being uploaded is handled by web server. So "upload time" means "creation time" for new file and "modification time" for overwriting. See what stat() returns and adjust your application code to it.

Comment: It's getting a timestamp of some type but I don't think it's the upload time. I've done some research in case and come across **clearstatcache()** which I implemented as well, but the time doesn't seem to change.

Comment: Interestingly, if I test it locally, the files that I upload will count as being last updated at the time uploaded - just not the files on FTP..